# Capybara - ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "#newProposal"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

Здравствуйте.

Есть следующий фрагмент теста:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'A contract' do
  before do
    @project = create(:project)
    @client = @project.user
    @contractor = create(:contractor)
    @contractor.contractor_info = create(:contractor_info)
    @contractor.contractor_info.source_languages << @project.source_languages
    @contractor.contractor_info.target_languages << @project.target_languages

    sign_in_contractor(@contractor)

    visit project_url(id: @project)
    page.find("#newProposal").click
    #click_link("Post Proposal")

    expect(current_path).to eq(new_project_proposal_path(project_id: @project.slug))

    fill_in 'Amount', with: 50
    fill_in I18n.t('proposals.new.description_placeholder'), with: 'X' * 60

    click_button 'Post Proposal'

    expect(current_path).to eq(project_path(id: @project))
    @proposal = @project.proposals.last

    log_out(@contractor)
  end
................................................................................
```

на строке `page.find("#newProposal").click` показывает ошибку  **ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "#newProposal"**

На вьюшке projects/show есть данная ссылка с данным id:

```
<% if contractor_signed_in? %>
    <% if policy(Proposal).create? && @project.available? %>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= link_to new_project_proposal_path(@project), class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block", id: "newProposal" do %>
        <span class="icon icon-plus pull-left m-b"></span><%= t('proposals.new_proposal') %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
    <% end %>

  <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
    <div class="panel panel-default m-b">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h4><%= t('sidebar.about_client') %></h4>
        <p><strong><%= t('user.name') %>:</strong> <%= @project.user.fullname %></p>
        <p><strong>First_name:</strong></p>
        <p><strong><%= t('projects.projects_posted') %>:</strong> <%= @project.user.projects.size %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Ставил брекпоинт в тесте перед нажатием ссылки. Проверяю current_path равен  "/projects/translation1-048fc3". Находимся на странице проекта, как и должно быть.

Почему капибара не видет данную ссылку? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: 1. Желательно показать html код который получается при рендеринге шаблона. Например чуть выше есть `if` из-за которого ссылка может не показываться вообще. 2. Если она, всё же, есть в html, не скрывается ли она например стилями?

Comment: а как при тесте посмотреть какой рендерится шаблон? В реальном проекте рендерится как положено.

Comment: если я правильно помню, метод `html`. Если удобнее, то можно использовать `save_page` или `save_and_open_page`. На всякий случай, [вот ссылка на документацию](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session)

Comment: спасибо. пробую

Comment: @dev85 Capybara позволяет даже скриншоты страниц делать (метод save_screenshot).